# Given an array of EventEmitters, listen for only the first event

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code, I have an array of `EventEmitter` objects. I know that at some point, one of them will fire an event called `launched`.

I only want to listen for the *first* event fired by an emitter in this array, and ignore any subsequent events.

My current code is:

```js
emitterArray.forEach(emitter => {
    emitter.once('launched', () => { console.log('Event fired!') });
});
```

However, this will wait for every emitter in the array to fire the event once.

I want the program to end after the exactly *one* of the emitters has fired this event exactly *once*.

**Note:** Terminating the process with `process.exit` in the event listener is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In your module, you can initialise a global (top module level) flag to false and make every event handler to check for that flag.

```
if (flag) {
  return
}

flag = true
console.log('Event fired')
```

Since node.js is single-thread, you shouldn't get any race conditions there and even when all the event handlers will get triggered, you can control which of them will actually run its code.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: While this does work, the node.js process will hang after all other code is executed, waiting for the event to fire on every emitter. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: You could save the callback as a const variable or register it as a function and as soon as you get it called, you'll unregister it from other event emitters